# I'm stuck on a Java project, all of the scenarios in my if statements keep getting calculated

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm working on a point system calculator thing, just learning more about Java and such but I've come into a problem, when I try to put in one of my scenario amounts, it prints every possible scenario in my if statements. Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

```
    double basepoints = 0.00;
    double spend = 0.00;
    double adjpnt = 0.00;

    //Prompts the user for their total spend in $, this will calculate the point system.
    //In this scenario the customer is incentivised to spend more money at one time due to
    // gaining exponentially more points based on spend.
    System.out.println("Enter Your Total Spend.");

    spend = scan.nextDouble();
    basepoints = (spend * 10);


    System.out.println("Your base points for this purchase is " + (Math.round(basepoints) )+ ". Calculating the bonuses for this purchase...");
    System.out.println("");
    if (spend < 20){
        adjpnt = (basepoints);
        System.out.println("You don't receive any bonuses this time. Sorry that you're poor. You have added " + adjpnt + " points into your account. Have a nice day.");
    }if (spend < 50 || (spend > 20)){
        adjpnt = (basepoints * 1.25);
        System.out.println("We have increased your point gain this purchase by a quarter.  " + adjpnt + " points have been added to your account. Have a nice day.");
    }if (spend < 100 || (spend > 50));{
        adjpnt = (basepoints * 1.5);
        System.out.println("Decent purchase. We're gonna throw in a little extra for you, 1.5x the amount of points to be exact.  " + adjpnt + " points have been added to your account. Have a nice day.");
    }if (spend < 200 || (spend > 100));{
        adjpnt = (basepoints * 1.75);
        System.out.println("Have 1.75x the extra points on us.  " + adjpnt + " points have been added to your account. Have a nice day.");
    }if (spend == 69){
        System.out.println("nice.");
    }
```

Comment: `(spend < 50 || (spend > 20))` is always true.

Comment: In other words, all those `||` should probably be `&&`

Comment: You should learn how to use `else`. It would make this simpler.

Comment: @khelwood, with the trailing semicolon `if (spend < 100 || (spend > 50));` the condition does not matter at all.

Comment: Also ``if (spend < 200 || (spend > 100));``. The semicolon means that the if-statement executes an empty statement.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the mentioned issues with `||` and missing `else`, there are some extra `;` after `if` statements which completely ignore any condition.

So, the typos must be fixed and the statements should be simplified using `else` to define the non-overlapping ranges and select only specific value of `adjpnt`; `nice` condition should be checked when appropriate:

```java
System.out.println("Your base points for this purchase is " + (Math.round(basepoints) )+ ". Calculating the bonuses for this purchase...\n");
if (spend < 20) {
    adjpnt = basepoints;
} else if (spend < 50) {
    adjpnt = basepoints * 1.25;
} else if (spend < 100) {
    adjpnt = basepoints * 1.5;
    if (spend == 69) {
        System.out.println("nice.");
    }
} else if (spend < 200) {
    adjpnt = basepoints * 1.75;
} else { // this needs to be added to assign bonus correctly
    adjpnt = basepoints * 2;
}
```

Comment: You are a legend, thank you very much for your help